# Is every covariance operator the covariance of a measure?

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, kernels

Let $X$ be a topological linear space over $\mathbb R$ which is complete and Hausdorff with a dual space that separates points. Let $k : X^* \to X$ be an arbitrary covariance operator. i.e., any continuous linear map which is symmetric and nonnegative-definite: $\psi[k\varphi] = \varphi[k\psi]$ and $\varphi[k\varphi] \ge 0$.

Suppose that the set $kX^* \subseteq X$ is separable.

Does there exist a probability measure $\mathbb P$ on $X$ which has $k$ as its covariance operator?

Theorem 4.4.6 of Vakhania (1981) answers this question in the affirmative when the space $X$ is separable and reflexive, but I do not know the answer in the non-reflexive case.

Comment: Note that there may not exist a Gaussian measure $\mathbb P$-- such operators are called "Gaussian covariance operators", not to be confused with so-called Gaussian kernels of the form $c(i,i') = \operatorname{exp}( -\|i-i'\|^2 / 2\sigma^2 )$.